# Import when its exists

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to import a json file if is exists, it working normally but i got a problem.

When exists:
Working normally.
When **NOT** exists:
Getting a error, `Cannot find module '../../config.json' or its corresponding type declarations.`

```js
access("./config.json")
.then(() => {
  const config = (
    await import("../../config.json", { assert: { type: "json" } })
  ).default;
  this.questions = config;
  this.validate();
})
.catch(() => {
  // Some codes.
})
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Control_flow_and_error_handling#exception_handling_statements

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is - the system seems to be telling you something which is correct. Could you expand a bit more on what you want to happen? How about testing to see if that file exists before trying to access it?

Comment: when the config.json is not exists, it asks some questions to create config.json file

Answer (score -2):

thank you guys for your helps, i figure it out by using fs instead of using import.